# Obtaining list of ProximityAlerts from LocationManager

Tags: android, locationmanager

**In short:** *How do I access `LocationManagerService.mProximityAlerts`?*

I'm trying to get multiple ProximityAlerts to work in Android. It would be helpful to track what is happening to my `PendingIntents` I've added as ProximityAlerts during debugging.

I've checked the Android source code and see that there is an `mProximityAlerts` map variable declared in `LocationManagerService`, but I have no idea how to access that variable while running (debugging) my app.

Querying the result of this call

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) caller.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

in the debugger while running doesn't seem to help, and I can't typecast `lm.mService` into `LocationManagerService` in the NetBeans watch list (if that's even the right track...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In short: How do I access LocationManagerService.mProximityAlerts?

You don't, at least not through the SDK. They may be included in the output of `adb shell dumpsys`.

Comment: Yeah, that does give me the info I needed, once I grepped out the noise. I suppose another option, though a bit of a schlepp, is to DL the android source and step through that?

Comment: @CjS: Since `LocationManagerService` is not in your process, unless you recompile the firmware in debug mode, I doubt you can run the OS in a debugger very well.